# Chrome Web Audio API - How does Plink work?

Tags: javascript, audio, midi, web-audio-api

I'm trying to understand the tone/sound generation component of the [Plink Chrome Experiment](http://labs.dinahmoe.com/plink/).

[This is the de-minified version](http://pastebin.com/0zfR0DNk) of what I think controls this.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this. How are the sound effects achieved?

*NB: I am almost certain it's some sort of MIDI-on-the-fly-instrument generation, but I'm not entirely sure.*

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking here. It's definitely using MIDI. The sounds are all loaded as .ogg files, so nothing is being generated with the Web Audio API (via oscillators). There's some code here for delay/chorus and things like that... but I'm not sure if it's actually being used in the app or if it's just part of some library that's being loaded. Hard to really get a great overall picture of how everything works because it's 8300 lines of code.

Comment: I didn't catch that part. I was wondering if it was some kind of digital synthesizer or it's preloading already generated sounds. Looks like the latter.